# Plot multiples of a variable

Tags: plotting, variable

If I am plotting a square wave s.t.:

```
$Assumptions = {k, p} ∈ Reals && {k, p} > 0
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{2 k, 2 p < x < 4 p}, {0, 0 < x < 2 p}, {0, 4 p < x}}]
```

Is there a way that I can plot this without setting `k` and `p` equal to something (for example 1)?

An additional question, is there a way to evaluate `f[x]` without giving `k` and `p` values? E.g.:

```
In[65]:= f[3 p]
Out[66]= Piecewise[{{2 k, 2 p < 3 p < 4 p}, {0, True}}]
```

would instead evaluate as

```
In[65]:= f[3 p]
Out[66]= 2 k
```

Thank you all for you time,

Edited to add that I am trying to make a plot similar to [image: squarewell]

but with a square wave. Notice that the units for the range are multiples of E.

Comment: 1) There is no good way to plot `f` without assigning values for $p$ and $k$; if the latter are not specified, then `f` is really a function of 3 variables; your best bet would then be some kind of `ContourPlot3D`. 2) Most functions don't take assumptions into consideration automatically; try perhaps `Simplify[f[3 p]]`, or more directly `Refine[f[3 p]]` (which should be invoked automatically by `Simplify` anyway).

Comment: ContourPlot3D is the wrong way to go about it. Looking to plot something with units as shown in this graphic: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iIQEL.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption `{k, p} > 0` is not equivalent to `k > 0 && p > 0`, likewise `{k, p} ∈ Reals` is not what you intend, but it's not necessary anyway, as it is implied by `k > 0 && p > 0`. So with

```
$Assumptions = k > 0 && p > 0
```

you can do (as noted by @MarcoB)

```
Simplify[f[3 p]] 
(* 2 k *)
```

A typical way to plot this type of thing is by rescaling to use dimensionless variables:

```
Plot[Simplify[f[x p]/k], {x, 0, 6}, AxesLabel -> {p, k}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to explicitly label each tick with the units you can do

```
Plot[Simplify[f[x p]/k], {x, 0, 6}, 
  Ticks -> {{1, p} # & /@ Range[6], {1, k} # & /@ Range[0, 2, .5]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.